# Git-Tfs: Pull a TFS changeset into existing git repository

Tags: tfs, git-tfs

I've got a git repository that was migrated from a TFS repository.  There is currently no link between the repositories.

If I use `git tfs list-remote-branches {http://...TFSRepo}`, I can see the branches in TFS.

What I want to do is be able to pull a TFS changeset into my current git repository -- preferably as a commit, but I'd take just pulling the changes into the current branch.

`quick-clone` doesn't do what I need as it creates a new git repository (buried in my existing git repository...)

Is is possible to perform a pull of a single TFS changeset using the `git-tfs` extensions?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git on the server side for TFS?

Comment: @MrHinsh TFVC on the server side

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pull only one changeset in an existing git repository that is not a git-tfs repository.

But you've got 2 possibilities to achieve your goal...

- The first is to do a `quick-clone` in a new repository and then add this repository has a remote and fetch the commit you want.
- The second is more tricky, less sure to work because you must understand how git-tfs works.

Amend the last commit to add at the end of the commit message something like that:

```
git-tfs-id: [https://tfs.codeplex.com:443/tfs/TFS16]$/valtechgittfs/BugMerge;C31467
```

with :

```
git-tfs-id: [https://url.tfs.server:/tfs/TeamCollection]$/ProjectName/BranchName;CchangesetId
```

where you specify as the changeset id, the one of the last changeset before the one you want to fetch. Then, if you have at least the v0.20 of git-tfs, then, fetch changesets...